# PHP: compare two strings for existence of 2 same words in both of them

Tags: php, string

I need to create a function that will return true or false based on comparison results.

I have two strings:

```
$one = 'sample product - White - Large'; // White is separate key, and large is separate too
$two = 'White Large';
```

Do you know any quick way for doing that task? Exploding two strings might not be safe as some strings instead of White will have: Blue - Black - Large. So I'm looking for existence of Blue - Black.

Another example of my data is:

```
$one = 'sample product - White - Blue - Large';  // White - Blue is separate key, Large is separate too.
```

If someone have any ideas on how to do it, I would really appreciate it.

Thanks,
eloleon

Answer (score 7):

I'd go for a strategy like that:

1. explode the strings into arrays by whitespaces (using regexes)
2. use [array_intersect()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php) to find matches

Comment: I'll give a shot to array_intersect(). My only fear is that I need to do it on at least 10000 strings.
Thanks arkascha

Comment: If you have a large amount of strings to compare and have to make many comparisions the costs of preparing the comparisions might get huge, indeed. In such case it might be worth storing the words as a 'word index' in a database whilst creating (storing) the strings instead of handling it all in php. The principle of comparision is unchanged, but you safe having to prepare (explode) the strings again and again.

Comment: Actually I will create tables in db for storing key words, as array_intersect() won't work in my case as I need to check if there are only one or two key words. And key words might be completely unpredictable i.e. 'White - Blue with some of Blue' etc etc.
Here is my output for array_intersect()
$one = sample product - White - Blue - Large
$two = White - Blue Large

Array ( [2] => - [3] => White [4] => - [5] => Blue [6] => - [7] => Large )

Thanks again arkascha